# Algebra problem about Ker and Im

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a problem with this linear algebra exercise.

A) Find an orthonormal basis with respect upon the Euclidean product for a vector space in $\mathbb{R}^3$, generated by those vectors: $(1, 2, -1)$, $(-1/2, -1, -1)$, $(1, 2, 1)$.

B) Write two linear applications $f, g ~~ \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\ker(f) = \text{Im}(g) \neq 0, \mathbb{R}^3$

**Solution 1-st point**

Calling $v_1, v_2, v3$ the three vectors, I put them into a matrix $\mathsf{A}$:

$$\mathsf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
1, &  2 &  -1 \\ 
-1/2 &  -1 &  -1 \\ 
1 &  2 &  1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then I reduce it with simple methods, obtaining in the end this matrix

$$\mathsf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
1, &  2 &  0 \\ 
0 &  0 &  1 \\ 
0 &  0 &  0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which means I have two vectors

$$v_1 = (1, 2, 0)$$
$$v_2 = (0, 0, 1) = e_3$$

Which means the $v_2$ vector is already orthonormal.

Now with Grahm-Schrmidt (I avoid the tedious calculations here) I found out the other orthonormal vector

$$v'_1 = \left(1/25, 2/25, 0\right)$$

And I found the orthonormal basis required:

$$\{e_3, v'_1\}$$

**I'm now stuck on point B).. any help?**

Comment: What's the relation between those two points? I can't see it...

Comment: @Joanpemo Indeed I think there is no relation! It's just a point I didn't understand!

Comment: Why did you compute a third (orthonormal) vector for a two-dimensional space?

Comment: @amd Why a third? I only have two...

Comment: Never mind. I misunderstood what you meant by “other orthonormal vector." However, $\|v_1'\|\ne 1$, so it’s incorrect. Looks like you squared instead of taking a square root. You didn’t need to use G-S, anyway—since $v_1$ and $v_2$ were already orthogonal, all you needed to do was normalize them both.

Comment: @amd Ops.. right!! I'll correct it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\;f,g\,$ by the matrices

$$f\to\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;g\to \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $\;\dim\ker f=1<\dim\text{ Im}\,g=2\;$  , so they can't be equal . In fact, we could have chosen $\;f=g\;$ in this example.

Added: But we can also have

$$f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\x\\x\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;g\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$\ker f=\left\{\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\;\;\right\}=\text{Im}\,g$$

Comment: @TimeMaster Only after reading your above comment I wondered and then read your comment again, and noticed you wanted **equality** of the kernel and image. I added an example of this in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry if I deleted the comment. After reading the edit I thought my comment was wrong so I deleted it...